# Determining standard file locations under Linux

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, posix, freebsd

Is there a standard way of determining file locations under Linux?  Even better, are there any POSIX API's which allow the retrieval of standard file locations?

For example, how can I determine a user's home directory?  Or, how can I determine the proper location for system configuration files?

I know that typically these locations would be "/home/username" or "/etc/".  Should I just hardcode the paths as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path to the current user's home directory is in the environment variable `HOME`.  (I know systems where home dirs are spread over several partitions (say, `/vol/vol[number]/[first letter]/[user name]`) and not located in `/home/`.)

For other users, there's `getpwent` (and `getpwent_r`), which pull the home directory from the passwd entry.

For the other directories, there is the [File System Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/), which most Linux distros adhere to and some other OSen as well.

I don't think there's an API for this. Thus, if a system does things differently, you're on your own -- good luck! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The current user's home directory can be found in the HOME environment variable. For other users, you can use the [getpwnam or getpwuid functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) (or the _r variants) to look up another specified user's home directory, among other things.

Answer (score -1):

I know that you didn't ask this, however if you're looking to find the location of an executable, you can use `which`